# How to add typescript paths to storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, storybook

I have a react application with a custom Webpack configuration.
After adding Webpack aliases that matches **tsconfig.json** file *compilerOptions->paths* field the aliases were recognized by webpack.

Since storybook comes with a built in Webpack configuration, my aliases are not read by Storybook and I'm getting the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve <path with typescript alias> in <some folder path>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Storybook main.js file, add the following:

```
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  ...,
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
       config.resolve.plugins = [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()];<-- this line
       return config;
  }
```

};

You can install **tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin** using the following command from the folder in which your application's package.json file resides:

```
npm i tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin -D
```

Solution was derived from this discussion:
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6316

Answer (score 9):

For future vistors of this question, since 15th July of 2022 storybooks can use [Vite instead Webpack](https://storybook.js.org/blog/storybook-for-vite/).

In that case I recommend using `vite-tsconfig-paths` instead of `tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin`. *If you are using TS paths in Vite, you probably already have this package installed.*

Add this to your [`.storybook/main.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/builder-vite#customize-vite-config)

```
const { mergeConfig } = require("vite")
const { default: tsconfigPaths } = require('vite-tsconfig-paths')

module.exports = {
  // your previous configs and more...
  viteFinal(config, { configType }) {
    return mergeConfig(config, {
      plugins: [
        tsconfigPaths()
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Storybook is offering Vite builder in addition to Webpack but WebPack is still the default

Answer (score 1):

In Storybook version **7 and above**, a new feature was introduced that allows *[frameworks](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/frameworks)* to manage all conventions in a given project automatically. This includes handling Absolute Imports and Module path aliases.

For example, the Next.js framework, provided with Storybook, can manage these paths for you. You can find more details on this [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/nextjs#Typescript). This means, with the right framework in place, you can eliminate the need for manual alias configuration in your project.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to accepted solution:

If you prefer not to install an external library such as **tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin**, you can create a custom file, say:
tsconfig-webpack-utils.js

and do something similar to the following:

```
const { compilerOptions } = require('../tsconfig.json');

function getAliases() {
    const baseUrl = getTSBaseUrl();
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(compilerOptions.paths).map(([key, value]) => {
            return [
                key.replace(/\/\*\*?$/,''),
                value.map(entryPath => path.resolve(__dirname, baseUrl, entryPath.replace(/\/\*\*?$/,'/')))
            ]
        }));
    }

function getTSBaseUrl() {
    return path.resolve(__dirname, `../${compilerOptions.baseUrl}`);
}

exports.addTsDefinitionsToWebpack = function(webpackConfig) {
    if (!webpackConfig.resolve.modules) {
        webpackConfig.resolve.modules = ['node_modules'];
    }
    webpackConfig.resolve.modules.push(getTSBaseUrl());
    webpackConfig.resolve.alias = {
        ...webpackConfig.resolve.alias,
        ...getAliases()
    };
}
```

This solution only works for very simple aliases. It is recommended to use an appropriate library or to expand this solution according to your needs.

You can then use it as follows in every webpack config you require it:

```
addTsDefinitionsToWebpack(webpackConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the current answers, it took several steps together for my setup to work.

- Add stories to `include` in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"include": ["ts/**/*", "playwright/tests/*", "stories/*"]
```

- [eslint ignorePatterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76572567/lint-staged-throwing-eslint-warning-for-ignored-storybook-config-file), in `.eslintrc.json`:

```
"ignorePatterns": [
  "!.storybook"
],
```

- `npm install -D vite-tsconfig-paths`
- Add to `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths()],
})
```