# Lint-staged throwing ESLint warning for ignored Storybook config file

Tags: eslint, storybook, lint-staged

I am currently developing a component library in React within a mono-repository. I have the `lint-staged` package to run my linting and unit testing NPM scripts when I make a commit to the repository.

I'm currently experiencing a warning `"File ignored by default.  Use a negated ignore pattern (like "--ignore-pattern '!<relative/path/to/filename>'") to override"` for `.storybook/main.js`.

I have tried adding `!./storybook/*` to my `.eslintignore` file but I'm now out of ideas.

If I run `yarn lint` from the command line then I do not see the same error so it seems something very specific to `lint-staged`. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also experiencing exact same issues. I tried the same trouble shootings as you described. I'm also out of ideas...

Answer (score 1):

In your `eslint` configuration add an `ignorePatterns` key.

For instance add this to your `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "ignorePatterns": ["!.storybook"]
  ...
}
```

Comment: This works, great! But why is it necessary to explicitly include the .storybook folder? Is it because of the leading dot in the folder name? Something else?